# which is the reason to use lambda in this scenario?

Tags: scheme

For what I know in functional languages is common to use lambda for referring to anonymous functions, but I do not see to be really useful to use:

```
(define square  
   (lambda (x) (* x x)))
```

instead of

```
(define (square x)
   (* x x))
```

why is the first form used in almost all documents that I found regarding Scheme?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I always use this syntax because it is explicit. `lambda` defines a function. Functions have no name. Then you assign this function to a variable. Variables have names. The form `(define (f x) ...)` is merely syntactic sugar for a very common case, but obscures the fact that scheme is a lisp-1.